# Trace from aspx.cs file

Tags: c#, asp.net, frontend, debugview, outputdebugstring

How can I trace from the client side of a ASP.NET web application ? I'm trapped in a `aspx.cs` file and I really need some fast simple debugging. I tried `System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine` without success: nothing appeared in DebugViewer when I refreshed the page in browser.

Thanks!

**Edit**: Adding the Trace attribute to the page Directive in my aspx file did trace `Trace.Write`, but I don't want all the other bulk trace (some hundred lines)

**Edit 2**: I'm not using Visual Studio and I don't want it if only for tracing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options

Here's a link to the MSDN article [How to: Enable Tracing for an ASP.NET Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x5wc973%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

You can view trace info by going to `http://localhost:<portnumber>/trace.axd`

If you're using Visual Studio you can use:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("This appears in the output window!")
```

Comment: The first link worked as I wanted (DebugView) by adding in web.config:
`<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <trace enabled="true" mostRecent="true" localOnly="true" writeToDiagnosticsTrace="true"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>`

But there's still a problem - how can I get rid of the "aspx.page" log entries: `[8404] aspx.page: Begin PreInit 
[8404] aspx.page: End PreInit 
[8404] aspx.page: Begin Init 
[8404] aspx.page: End Init 
`

Comment: I'm not sure that you can.  You can use `Trace.warn` instead of write and they will show up as red instead of black to stand out a little better.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it to you in a few days if it is as good as it gets.